# How to fix ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and multilabel-indicator targets for model?

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning, neural-network

I have created a model for multiclass classification where output variable has 6 classes. I am getting an error when I try to obtain the accuracy score. I have tried other SO answers but the answers did not help.

**Code**

```
#Converting Target Variable to Numeric
lang = {'US':1, 'UK':2, 'GE':3, 'IT':4, 'FR':5, 'ES':6} 
df.language = [lang[item] for item in df.language] 

#Creating Input Features and Target Variables
X= df.iloc[:,1:13]
y= df.iloc[:,0]

#Standardizing the Input Features
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

#Train Test Split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

#Model
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_normal', input_dim=12))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_normal'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_normal'))

#Output Layer
model.add(Dense(7, activation = 'softmax', kernel_initializer='random_normal'))

#Compiling the neural network
model.compile(optimizer ='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics =['accuracy'])

#Fitting the data to the training dataset
model.fit(X_train,y_train, batch_size=5, epochs=100)

#Make predictions
pred_train = model.predict(X_train)
pred_test = model.predict(X_test)  
   
print('Train Accuracy = ',accuracy_score(y_train,pred_train.round()))
print('Test Accuracy = ',accuracy_score(y_test,pred_test.round()))
```

**Error**

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and multilabel-indicator targets
```

**Values held by variables**
I am adding the values held by required variables. I believe the number of output variables that I am receiving in incorrect as there are multiple outputs for 1 value.

**y_train**

```
101    4
250    1
130    2
277    1
157    2
      ..
18     6
47     5
180    1
131    2
104    4
```

**pred_train**

```
array([[0.13525778, 0.15400752, 0.14303789, ..., 0.14364597, 0.14196989,
        0.14313765],
       ...,
       [0.13389133, 0.15622397, 0.14272076, ..., 0.14345258, 0.142379  ,
        0.14322434]], dtype=float32)
```

**y_test**

```
57     5
283    1
162    2
237    1
107    4
      ..
182    1
173    1
75     3
251    1
55     5
```

**pred_test**

```
array([[0.13440262, 0.15538406, 0.14284912, 0.13841757, 0.14352694,
        0.14221355, 0.14320615],
       .....,
       [0.13503768, 0.1543666 , 0.14298101, 0.13881107, 0.14361957,
        0.14203095, 0.14315312]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: What are the values of, `y_train`, `pred_train`, `y_test`, `pred_test`?

Comment: @B200011011 I have added the values in the question, please have a look.

Comment: Try with [jaccard_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score.html#sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score). Furthermore, you can't predict with trained data so `pred_train ` it's not useful.

Comment: @Omar , if I can't predict with trained data then how will I compare the accuracy of model on train and test data?

Comment: @IshanDutta that's why you have your test data. I.e: it can't learn "1 is an apple" and then predict 1. It knows the result of 1. You will only blur your results! The tested data is new so it's with this data where you put to test its accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`predict` returns the probability of the sample belonging of each class, but `accuracy_score` required the class labels. You have to get the class labels from the predictions. Use

```
accuracy_score(y, np.argmax(pred_train, axis=1))
```

`np.argmax` returns the label of the class with the highest probability and since you made a prediction on a batch of data rather then a single sample you will have to use `axis=1`.